# Problems in deleting rows from selected Datagridview in MySQL database

Tags: c#, c++, mysql-workbench, windows-forms-designer

I am not able to update my MySQL database after delete a selected row from `DataGridView`. When running the `ExecuteNonQuery()`, I am getting error which says:

> System.Invalid.Operation.Exception: Connection must be valid and open.

However I have made a correct connection. Still I get problem.

My code is below:

```
private: System::Void button9_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=****;password=********";
    MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
    conDataBase->Open();
    try 
    {
        if (MessageBox::Show("Sure you wanna delete?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo) == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes)
        {
            for each(DataGridViewCell^ oneCell in dataGridView1->SelectedCells)
            {
                if (oneCell->Selected) {
                    dataGridView1->Rows->RemoveAt(oneCell->RowIndex);
                    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase1 = gcnew MySqlCommand("Delete from Dinslaken_DB.Configuration where Memory=" + dataGridView1->CurrentRow->Index +"");
                    cmdDataBase1->ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //sda->Update(dbdataset);
                }   
            }           
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ex)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: For .Net use C# instead of C++. The syntax of C++.Net is very ugly. Don't punish yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the command object

```
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase1 = gcnew MySqlCommand("Delete from Dinslaken_DB.Configuration where Memory=" + dataGridView1->CurrentRow->Index +"");
```

but you haven't set its command property. Most likely second argument to the above command constructor should be the connection. Check that.

So your command constructor should be:

```
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase1 = gcnew MySqlCommand("Delete from Dinslaken_DB.Configuration where Memory=" + dataGridView1->CurrentRow->Index +"", conDataBase);
```

Also don't forget to close the connection.